# Updating ListView in Fragment - Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, xamarin

I'm new to Android dev, so it's really weird for me what's wrong in this code.

I've spent a lot of time in xamarin forums and finally I gave up, so asking your help.

```
namespace App1.Fragments
{
    public class HomePage : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        private List<Model.Photo> photos;

        private ListView listview;
        private MyListViewAdapter adapter;
        private bool IsLoading = false;
        private int Treshhold = 10;
        private int PreviousTotalItemCount = 0;

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        public override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            try
            {
                var task = Task.Run(async delegate
                {
                    photos = await API.GetLatestPhotos();
                }).ContinueWith(delegate
                {
                    using(var h = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper))
                    {
                        h.Post(delegate
                        {
                            UpdateView(); // I cannot call this.RunOnUIThread(delegate{ //code });
                        });
                    }
                });

                task.Wait();
            }
            catch { }
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            photos = new List<Model.Photo>();

            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HomePage, container, false);

            listview = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List);
            adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, photos);
            listview.Adapter = adapter;
            listview.ScrollStateChanged += Listview_ScrollStateChanged;
            UpdateView();


            return view;
        }

        private void UpdateView()
        {
            if(adapter != null)
                adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private async void Listview_ScrollStateChanged(object sender, AbsListView.ScrollStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int last = listview.LastVisiblePosition;
            int total = listview.Adapter.Count;

            if(IsLoading && total > PreviousTotalItemCount)
            {
                IsLoading = false;
                PreviousTotalItemCount = total;
            }

            if((last + Treshhold) >= total && !IsLoading)
            {
                IsLoading = true;

                var items = await API.GetLatestPhotos(API.LastPhotoID);


                foreach(var item in items)
                    photos.Add(item);

                adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<Model.Photo>
    {
        List<Model.Photo> items;
        Activity context;

        public MyListViewAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment context, List<Model.Photo> items) : base()
        {
            this.context = context.Activity;
            this.items = items;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override Model.Photo this[int position]
        {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = items[position];
            View view = convertView;
            if(view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyListView, null);

            Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Image), item.StoragePath);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

All data uploading, it's OK, but my listview doesn't update.

If I'm trying to call `adapter.NotifySetDataChanged()` not in UI thread, I've got `Skippen *n* frames. Too much work in current thread.`

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I deleted `OnResume` and `UpdateView` methods re-write my `OnCreate` method like this:

```
public override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    await Task.Run(async delegate
    {
        photos = await API.GetLatestPhotos();
        using(var h = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper))
        {
            h.Post(delegate
            {
                listview = this.Activity.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List);
                adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, photos);
                listview.Adapter = adapter;
                adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

So, basically, I duplicate code in `OnCreate` and in `OnCreateView` methods. Weird. =)

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine...

```
public override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //maybe show some kind of wait spinner?
    photos = await API.GetLatestPhotos();

    listview = this.Activity.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List);
    adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, photos);
    listview.Adapter = adapter;
}
```

When you are assigning the `Adapter`, you don't need to also call `NotifyDataSetChanged`. The data set will be refreshed when the adapter is set.

Also, since the code begins on the UI thread(`OnCreate` runs on the UI thread), the `await` call will return back to the UI thread. So there shouldn't be any special considerations needed for that.